# how to combine lof and lot to a list of figures AND tables

Tags: table-of-contents

How to combine lof and lot to a list of figures AND tables and additionally adding the words Table and Figure infront of the table numbers, respectively. The order should be according to the page numbers.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,doc,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the inner command of `caption` to always use `lof` and to add the word Figure or Table; also the spacing needs to be increased.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,doc,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand*\listfigurename{List of Figures and Tables}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\caption@@@addcontentsline[4]{%
  \addcontentsline{lof}{#2}{\protect\numberline{\csname #2name\endcsname~#3}{#4}}%
}
\renewcommand{\l@figure}{\@dottedtocline {1}{1.5em}{4.3em}}
\renewcommand{\l@table}{\@dottedtocline {1}{1.5em}{4.3em}}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Short Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\listoffigures

\newpage

\begin{figure}
a\caption{Caption of figure a}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
b\caption{Caption of table b}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
c\caption{Caption of table c}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
d\caption{Caption of table d}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would have expected a comment like "however it is horrible" :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Not necessarily. 

Comment: I don't like it at all, it's confusing, in my option, unless you have only 2 table and 3 figure...

Comment: @CarLaTeX I agree: this is only acceptable for a short list.